# OLEDB Database Connection

Tags: c#, .net

I am really having problem with my database connection on a C# project. I created my database in MS Access and whenever I run the query commands (the methods have been assigned to specific buttons), I get an error (`OledbException was unhandled`) on the `adapter.Fill(dataset);` line of code saying that

> No coinciden los tipos de datos en la expresión de criterios.

OR

> There is a mismatch in the data type in the criteria expression

```
namespace Repuesto
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection();
        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
        DataSet dataset = new DataSet();
        OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();

        string direction = Application.StartupPath + "\\Database1.accdb";

        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            InitializeData();
            FillDataGrid();
        }

        public void InitializeData()
        {
            connection.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + direction;
            connection.Open();
            command = connection.CreateCommand();
            connection.Close();
        }

        private void FillDataGrid()
        {
            dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
            dataset = new DataSet();
            connection.Open();
            command.CommandText = "select * from Consulta1 order by Id";
            adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(command);
            adapter.Fill(dataset);
            connection.Close();
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dataset.Tables[0];
        }

        public void DeleteRow()
        {
            dataset = new DataSet();
            connection.Open();
            command.CommandText = "delete from Consulta1 where Id = '" + dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString() + "'";
            adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(command);
            adapter.Fill(dataset);
            connection.Close();
            for (int i = 1; i < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                dataGridView1.Columns[i].Visible = true;
            }

            FillDataGrid();
        }

        public void AddRow()
        {
            Form1 form1 = new Form1();

            var dateRecibido = DateTime.Parse(form1.dateTimePickerFechaRecibida.Value.ToString()).ToShortDateString();
            var dateSalido = DateTime.Parse(form1.dateTimePickerFechaSalida.Value.ToString()).ToShortDateString();

            dataset = new DataSet();
            connection.Open();
            command.CommandText = "insert into Consulta1([Fecha Recepcion], [Cantidad Recibido], [Denominación], [Ubicación], [Nº Referencía], [Proveedor], [Fecha Salida], [Cantidad Salida]) values "
                + "('" + dateRecibido + "','" + form1.textBoxCantidadRecibido.Text + "','" + form1.textBoxDenominacion.Text
                + "','" + form1.textBoxUbicacion.Text + "','" + form1.textBoxNoReferencia.Text + "','" + form1.textBoxProveedor.Text + "','" + dateSalido + "','" + form1.textBoxCantidadSalido.Text + "')";

            adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(command);         
            adapter.Fill(dataset);
            connection.Close();
            for (int i = 1; i < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                dataGridView1.Columns[i].Visible = true;
            }

            FillDataGrid();
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone help explain why I'm getting this error?  Thanks!

Comment: It's not necessary to SHOUT your questions here. We can all read well. :-) You have three separate `adapter.Fill(dataset);` calls. Which one is throwing the exception? (I'm suspecting it's in `AddRow()`, and my psychic debugging skills tell me it's because you're using string concatenation to set the field values instead of properly parameterizing your SQL.) But you need to actually identify the problem, and you have that information right in front of you (we don't). Please [edit] your question to be more specific about where the problem is actually occurring.

Comment: :-).. They all throw the same exception. I am sorry but i am a novice in db connection and well it works if i input the values within the code but however when the input is done via textboxes, it throws the exception and its really stressing me up :-(

Comment: They can't **all** throw that exception, because at least one of them is a simple `SELECT *`, and it **cannot** have a data type mismatch. Check again. And (again), **don't use concatenation** to assign the values to the columns. Use `parameters` instead, where you can assign the proper data types to the columns. (Searching here for `[c#] parameterized query` should find you some results; in fact, the first two I saw seem very useful.)

Answer (score 0):

> Can anyone help explain why I'm getting this error? Thanks!

If you are using Microsoft Access (unless they changed this in a different version to tell Access its a date you need to use # instead of '. in your code for `dateRecibido`, you are preceding and ending with a ' (apostrophe). Try changing to a #

As you can see you are passing in a string when it is likely a date field:

```
var dateRecibido = DateTime.Parse(form1.dateTimePickerFechaRecibida.Value.ToString()).ToShortDateString();
            var dateSalido = DateTime.Parse(form1.dateTimePickerFechaSalida.Value.ToString()).ToShortDateString();
```

Comment: :..i have checked it...the data i am parsing to the database are of the same type but it stills throw the exception.